# Find triple sets in Pig Latin

Tags: apache-pig

Is it possible to find triple datasets in Pig? Let's say your data is:

```
bag1 Apple
bag1 Orange
bag2 Apple
bag2 Orange
bag2 Pineapple
bag3 Apple
bag3 Orange
bag3 Pineapple
bag4 Orange
bag5 Apple
bag5 Banana
```

In data above I want to count occurrence of (Apple,Orange,Pineapple)set inside each bag, which happens twice for bag2 and bag3. Is that possible?

Comment: did you try grouping by bag column and then using count on bags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A = LOAD 'BAG.csv' using PigStorage(' ') as (bag:Chararray, fruit:Chararray);

B = GROUP A by $0;

C = FILTER B BY COUNT(A)==3;

D = FOREACH C GENERATE group, A.$1 as FRUITS;

DUMP D;